# No video output M2N-SLI Deluxe

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure, troubleshooting

I was having issues where my monitors would randomly stop working ( while computer was still on), and could be fixed only by restarting the computer repeatedly ( typically 1-10 times ) and then it would fix for a while.

Well now it has become permanent and the computer turns on as if it is working just fine but there is absolutely no video output.

Hardware used(purchased from Newegg):

- https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131013
- https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817171031
- https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130061
- https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103751
- https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820220071

I have replaced the CMOS battery.  Tried different monitors.
I don't see any blown capacitors or burnt spots on motherboard or GPU.
All normal lights turn on and fans spin.
There are no beeps from POST because there is no internal speaker.
There is no internal GPU.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try swapping in another GPU, or swapping your GPU into another system to determine if the problem is the GPU or not.

Comment: Update: Tried the GPU in a known working computer and it worked fine.  What should I try next?

Comment: Update: Tried known good GPU and PSU from a different computer with the possible bad mobo.  Was able to get 3-4 boots, but then connected a keyboard and on that boot it didn't boot, and since then have not been able to get a good boot.  Disconnected keyboard and still nothing.

Comment: Update: Disconnected GPU and dispersed charges by holding a screw driver to the on switch on the board.  PC boots and windows loads now with current setup.  Put original GPU in with NEW PSU and one stick of RAM and seems to be working fine.  Put back original PSU and seems to be working FINE.    .............no idea at this point